# moving contents from cell to msgbox with spaces?

Tags: excel, vba, newline, msgbox

I've got an interesting problem - I'm trying to write VBA code that will take the contents of a cell and put it into a msgbox. The problem is that I can't figure how to put carriage returns into this string.

My code looks something like this.

```
Dim myMsg as string
myMsg = Worksheets("Data").cells(1,1)
msgBox myMsg
```

so, if cell `A1` contains...

```
THIS IS MY NEXT AND NOW THIS IS A NEW LINE
```

... how can I force a carriage return into the middle of that line?

Answer (score 4):

I never used VBA, but a quick search online gave me this:

```
 "some string" & vbCrLf & "next line"
```

and

```
 "some string " & chr(13) & "next line"
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new line is a message box, use vbCrLF.

So, let's say you wanted to put a new line every time there is a back slash.  You would use:

```
Msgbox Replace(ActiveCell.Value, "\", vbCrLF)
```

To fit within the bounds of your sample code, use:

```
Dim myMsg as string
Dim newLineCharacter as string

newLineCharacter = "\"  ' Replace with your delimiter

myMsg = Replace(Worksheets("Data").cells(1,1), newLineCharacter, vbCrLf)
msgBox myMsg
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends what your goal is. If you want to pre-formatting text in Excel prior to displaying on message box, wrap you lines using `<Alt+Enter>` in Excel, then you VBA will just look like this:

```
MsgBox Worksheets("Data").cells(1,1).value
```

If you intend to auto-wrap, write a function to cut the string and supply the length.

```
MsgBox WrapText(Worksheets("Data").cells(1,1).value, 20)
```